# MySQL and PHP not working together

Tags: php, sql, apache, wamp

I am actually ridicously stumped by this. I have downloaded php, MySQL and apache. Apache and php are working together, and it is wonderful. However whatever I do I cannot get php to work with MySQL. I'm using Windows 7 and PHP version 5.2.17 and Apache 2.2

I have gone into php.ini and uncommented out the lines `extension=php_mysql.dll`, `extension=php_mysqli.dll` and set the extention in Windows to this `extension=msql.dll`. I even changed the session path in php.ini to see if it would change anything. *Spoiler Alert* it didn't. I keep checking phpinfo() but the only information about MySQL and SQL that shows up is sql.safe_mode: off.

I cannot find any answers anywhere, well I have but all it tells me to do is uninstall and reinstall everything. Which I am trying to avoid at all costs. But if that is my only option, can you give suggestions about using WAMP and whether its easier than installing everything individually? Because I did not use WAMP and it took me forever to get this far.

Comment: Why did you do this? extension=msql.dll

Comment: Did you restart apache after updating the php.ini?

Comment: If this is for development and testing, I'd go for a WAMP bundle. My personal favourite is http://www.uniformserver.com/ very very easy to set up

Comment: Did you check if you actually have `php_mysqli.dll` in your php extensions directory (if I remember correctly, it is `ext` dir in your php installation directory)?

Comment: Have you instaled mysql as a service? Check if the service is started.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working together"? Is the mysql extension not loading, or are you unable to connect to your mysql database?

Comment: To install MySQl as a service, from zip file you need to issue a coomand like this: "C:\Server\MySQL\bin\mysqld.exe" --install MySQL --defaults-file=C:\Server\MySQL\my.ini  - where the first location is the location of the mysqld.exe file (where you have extracted MySQL) and the second is the location of your ini file.

Comment: Because it was a suggestion and I was desperate and I have restarted apache everytime I update. @somedev

Comment: I have `php_mysqli.dll` in my directory and I have updated `extension_dir`  @Cthulhu

Comment: I have installed mySQL as a service and it does work and can connect to the database only it will not connect to the database using php for some reason. @Gimmy

Comment: How are you trying to connect to the database in PHP? Can you show the code? And if you're getting any errors, can you show them?

Comment: `mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "password") or die(mysql_error()); 
 mysql_select_db("database") or die(mysql_error()); `

Comment: `PHP version 5.2.17`: Why such an old version? Download version 5.4.x

Answer (score 0):

Annabelle,

Are you editing the php.ini file directly or using the wampmanager menus to edit php.ini.

There are actually 2 php.ini files: 
the one in c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.2.17 which is used for the PHP CLI environment ( Command Line Interface )
and the one in c:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.x\bin\php.ini ( the one used by apache )

The reason for having 2 is a little complicated but if you ALWAYS use the wampmanager menu links to edit php.ini it will ensure ou always edit the one used by apache.

left click wampmanager icon in the system tray -> PHP -> php.ini

To check that the mysql and mysqli module are loaded go to localhost and from the wamp home page click on the phpinfo link. If the modules are loaded you should see them mentioned in the list of loaded modules in the CONFIGURATION section.